# Save contact number to mobile phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am working on a mobile website, and I am suppose to add contact number of my client to user's mobile phone (obviously on click of a button), I was wondering if this is possible using jQuery, JS, Jquery Mobile or HTML 5, like by using `<a href="tel:111222333">Call</a>` we can bring up cell phone dialer etc, thanks in advance

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html

Comment: Mobile Safari generally detects phone numbers and makes them clickable.  Not sure about other mobile browsers.  Using the tel: scheme is probably the closest cross-platform solution you'll find.

Comment: @MNet - Have you tried my idea ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that idea but doesnot work with android it shows the vcf,

Answer (score 4):

You just can't store directly contact on the phone using js or html5 stuff.

What you can try is creating a vcf card server side and redirect the client to download this newly generated vcf card... I've haven't yet tested this solution, but I think it can work.

Comment: this actually works, but with an additional click on the downloaded file (android 2.3)

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, phone numbers are automatically detected, even if they aren't tel links. When clicking them there are two options – call, or add to address book. This isn't something that you need to implement, the UA does it for you.

Comment: I think there is only a click to call, the user has to manually add the phone number to his contacts...

Comment: I just checked, on my iPod I get "Add to Contacts" and "Copy". I assume on a phone you also get "Call". I'm running the latest iOS, so things might be different on the older version.