# Mobile website contacts

Tags: javascript, mobile, contacts

I am currently working on creating contacts on mobile website.

I have already created the link to mobile number. But I want to rebuilt it so that there will be just some button and when you click on it it will automatically add the person into contacts. Is there any option using HTML and JS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure any phone would allow the browser (some website) to access data on the phone (such as your contacts list).

Edit: I guess there'll soon be ways to access contacts information from a web app, but seems like it'll be [read only](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/01/24/the-state-of-html5-mobile-in-2012/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6804246/1356601) answer? It suggests creation of a vcf that can then be downloaded on click of a button..